# DbType.Time ignored for IDbDataParameter.DbType (SqlClient)

Tags: c#, sql-server, ado.net

I have a habit of always using the generic abstractions in `System.Data` such as `IDbCommand` and `IDbDataParameter` for accessing data instead of the concrete implementations `System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDbCommand` and `System.Data.SqlClient.SqlParameter`, whenever possible, even if my application targets SQL Server.  I do this so that it is easier to port the application to another RDBMS in the future or to introduce database abstraction layers in between my application and SQL Server, as needed.  I have been using this pattern successfully for over a decade.

Today, however, I encountered some very odd behavior where using `IDbDataParameter` behaved unexpectedly.  Using code similar to this:

```
System.Data.IDbCommand cmd;
TimeSpan someTimeSpanValue;
...
System.Data.IDbDataParameter dataParameter = cmd.CreateParameter();
dataParameter.DbType = DbType.Time;
dataParameter.Value = someTimeSpanValue;
cmd.Execute();
```

ADO.NET complained when I executed my statement that it could not convert my `TimeSpan` to a `DateTime`.  The underlying database type that was being set based on this parameter was of type `TIME`. Confused, I traced the code and sure enough, when I set `dataParameter.DbType = DbType.Time` and then interrogate `dataParameter.DbType`, it returned `DbType.DateTime` instead of `DbType.Time` like I was setting it to.

I have a workaround to this code, which looks like this:

```
dataParameter.DbType = v.DbType; //v.DbType is the desire DbType for the command being prepared
if (v.DbType == DbType.Time && dataParameter.DbType != DbType.Time && dataParameter is System.Data.SqlClient.SqlParameter sqlParam)
    sqlParam.SqlDbType = SqlDbType.Time;
```

It seems when I set SqlDbType to SqlDbType.Time, then interrogate `IDbDataParameter.DbType`, it does return `DbType.Time` and everything works, though this code is now not as database agnostic as I would like.

Even stranger still, is that if set `IDbDataParameter.DbType` to `DbType.Time`   (which is its current value) *after* setting SqlDbType to SqlDbType.Time, it still changes to `DbType.DateTime`.

My question, after all that, is whether this is a defect in `System.Data.SqlClient`'s implementation of `IDbDataParameter` or if there is some setting that I am unaware of that causes this behavior (perhaps defaulting to pre-SQL 2008 compatibility) that I can adjust to avoid this hacky workaround?

Comment: From the source code [DbType.Date and DbType.Time should always be treated as setting DbType.DateTime instead](https://github.com/microsoft/referencesource/blob/master/System.Data/System/Data/SqlClient/SqlParameter.cs#L291).

Comment: This is due to the fact that the dbtype.time only supports up to 24h. to store timespan you should use datetime. Example output of timespan from 1 day 1.00:00:00, this is not a valid dbtype.time format

Comment: @DavidG looks like your comment is the correct answer.  According to that reference code this behavior is by design for backward compatibility.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @DavidG who posted a comment referencing the .NET source code.  Based on the reference code:

```
    override public DbType DbType {
        get {
            return GetMetaTypeOnly().DbType;
        }
        set {
            MetaType metatype = _metaType;
            if ((null == metatype) || (metatype.DbType != value) ||
                    // SQLBU 504029: Two special datetime cases for backward compat
                    //  DbType.Date and DbType.Time should always be treated as setting DbType.DateTime instead
                    value == DbType.Date ||
                    value == DbType.Time) {
                PropertyTypeChanging();
                _metaType = MetaType.GetMetaTypeFromDbType(value);
            }
        }
    }
```

I can infer that this behavior is by design based on the comments in the reference code.

Following up on `GetMetaTypeFromDbType(value)` [reference source](https://github.com/microsoft/referencesource/blob/3b1eaf5203992df69de44c783a3eda37d3d4cd10/System.Data/System/Data/SqlClient/SqlEnums.cs), it would appear this is consistent:

```
  internal static MetaType GetMetaTypeFromDbType(DbType target) {
        // if we can't map it, we need to throw
        switch (target) {
        case DbType.AnsiString:             return MetaVarChar;
        case DbType.AnsiStringFixedLength:  return MetaChar;
        case DbType.Binary:                 return MetaVarBinary;
        case DbType.Byte:                   return MetaTinyInt;
        case DbType.Boolean:                return MetaBit;
        case DbType.Currency:               return MetaMoney;
        case DbType.Date:
        case DbType.DateTime:               return MetaDateTime;
        case DbType.Decimal:                return MetaDecimal;
        case DbType.Double:                 return MetaFloat;
        case DbType.Guid:                   return MetaUniqueId;
        case DbType.Int16:                  return MetaSmallInt;
        case DbType.Int32:                  return MetaInt;
        case DbType.Int64:                  return MetaBigInt;
        case DbType.Object:                 return MetaVariant;
        case DbType.Single:                 return MetaReal;
        case DbType.String:                 return MetaNVarChar;
        case DbType.StringFixedLength:      return MetaNChar;
        case DbType.Time:                   return MetaDateTime;
        case DbType.Xml:                    return MetaXml;
        case DbType.DateTime2:              return MetaDateTime2;
        case DbType.DateTimeOffset:         return MetaDateTimeOffset;
        case DbType.SByte:                  // unsupported
        case DbType.UInt16:
        case DbType.UInt32:
        case DbType.UInt64:
        case DbType.VarNumeric:
        default:                            throw ADP.DbTypeNotSupported(target, typeof(SqlDbType)); // no direct mapping, error out
        }
    }
```

Based on this, it would appear that implementation of `IDbDataParameter.DbType` in `SqlParameter` simply does not support `DbType.Time` or any way to create a parameter of type `TIME`  using the `IDbDataParameter` interface, since none of those cases return `MetaTime`.  I conclude that the only way to get a parameter to reference a `TIME` type is to use the `SqlParameter.SqlDbType` instead.